# Do quadcopter propellers break the sound barrier?

Tags: propeller, noise, model-aircraft, quadcopter

I recently bought a quadcopter and noticed every time I fly it there is this weird buzzing noise. I have heard this noise on other quadcopters around the same size as mine(4in by 4in). On an airliner turbofan engine you can sometimes hear this weird buzzing sound from the engines, which this sound is the n1 fan spinning faster than the speed of sound and resulting in this loud buzzing sound. So is my little quadcopter motors going supersonic or is it something else?[image]Source:(dynomodels.co.uk)

Comment: I cant find good tags for this question. If there is a good tag for this question besides supersonic than please add it to the question thanks.

Comment: @mins does that mean length of the blade. If is that I measured 0.5in in lenght of each of the 16 blades.

Comment: @Ethan diameter means twice the radius (i.e. the width of the entire circle through which the blades spin.) If you have an even number of blades on the prop, you can measure this as the distance from one blade tip to the tip of the opposite blade. Otherwise, you can measure it as 2 x the distance from the center of the drop to a blade tip.

Comment: The "buzz saw" noise from jet engine fans is created by high vibration amplitudes in the blades, not from supersonic airflow. A common cause is aerodynamic flutter creating a feedback loop which excites the vibration modes. This doesn't necessarily occur at the maximum N1 speed. Eliminating these problems can be challenging - for example I was once involved with a situation where *less than 1 part in 1 million* of the total power output of the engine was "getting into the wrong place" and generating the nasty noise.

Comment: Is that your actual quadcopter on the picture?

Comment: @mins Yes its the same model

Comment: I found [this EDF (electric ducted fan)](http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__51645__Dr_Mad_Thrust_90mm_12_Blade_Alloy_EDF_w_Metal_Rotor1300kv_3300w_8S_.html) where the rotor tips get up to Mach 0.6. Beyond issues of aerodynamics, you need to consider how much strength it requires to whip around those blades without them exploding. I've blown up cheap 6" props by running them at about 25000 RPM (that's also a tip speed of almost M 0.6, now that I calculate it...and that only cost me about ~\$17 instead of \$170 for that EDF).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Almost certainly not. Given the comments specifying a $0.5$ inch radius (blade length,) that means the circumference of the path of the blade tips would then be

$$2 \pi \cdot 0.5 \, \text{inches} \approx 3.1415 \, \text{inches} \approx 0.2618 \,\text{feet}$$

To get to the speed of sound (which is approximately $1,126 \,\frac{\text{ft}}{\text{s}}$ at sea level,) that means you'd need to have the fan spinning at

$$\frac{1,126}{0.2618} \approx 4,301 \,\text{Hz} \approx 258,060 \,\text{rpm}$$

Needless to say, that's not happening unless you have one seriously expensive quadcopter.

The buzzing you hear is probably either the frequency at which the motor is spinning or, perhaps, the frequency of some oscillation of the fan blades. Most likely, though, it's just the frequency of the motor/fan.

Comment: Each rotor has its own motor, so each prop will rotate a close-to but not necessary the same rate.  This may produce a [beat note](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_(acoustics)) which could be the audible artifact the OP is noticing.

Comment: To give an idea of what 258,000 RPM is: the electrons in the Large Hadron collider are doing about 666,666 RPM (0.00 009 seconds per rotation).

Comment: @NateKerkhofs: Isn't that mostly just a function of the LHC's size? I'd expect smaller accelerators to have much higher RPMs, since the track is so much shorter.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Yeah, that's definitely another possibility. In all likelihood, it's a mix of several different things, including the fundamental of each motor, some harmonics, some extra oscillations of the fans (which probably aren't perfectly balanced,) and various interference patterns between all of the above, but a beat is definitely a distinct possibility for the source of the buzzing sound.

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah, that's just c / circumference of the LHC. You're right that any particle accelerator will have particle speeds near c and, thus, have circuits per minute almost equal to c / their circumference. Also, as a slight nitpick, LHC doesn't normally (if ever?) accelerate electronics. They primarily use protons and lead nuclei.

Comment: Arg. That should say "accelerate electrons," not "accelerate electronics." One would hope that they don't accelerate their electronics. :)

Comment: Comparing RPM between X and Y, i.e. a rotor and the LHC, isn't really fair unless you mention the diameter.

Comment: @NickT Yeah, there's a big difference between being concerned whether something will reach Mach 1 or not vs. being concerned with how close to **c** it is.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs: On the other hand the speed of sound can be achieved in the LHC at **0.01 rpm**, this gives an idea of what is the speed of sound with large diameters (9 km). Now what about a music CD? [It can't!](http://www.qedata.se/e_js_n-cdrom.htm#inledning) It is destroyed before reaching this speed, according to this guy.

Comment: @mins If it actually contained sea-level air pressure (I'd assume it doesn't,) Mach 1 would be about 0.75 circuits per minute in the LHC, since Mach 1 is a bit over 12 miles per minute at sea level. Still, the point remains that LHC is very large.

Comment: @reirab: Ahhh yes, I took 27 km/mn for 27 km/s. And yes if would be better to restore [a bit of atmosphere](http://www.lhc-closer.es/taking_a_closer_look_at_lhc/0.high_vacuum) for the occasion. And some heating.

Comment: On the other hand, if the numbers were adjusted to 12" propeller (6" radius), a 12x increase, the motor was a 1000kv motor, and hooked up in 8s, then the theoretical speed at 4.2v per cell would be 1.5x the speed of sound - but this is still unrealistic as the force of the air would significantly reduce the speed, and I am not sure how the engine efficiency relates to the RPM (i.e. does it slow down, or just consume more power) - just food for thought that in theory it is possible for a sufficiently powerful quadcopter propeller/motor combination to break the speed of sound

Comment: @user2813274 For 12" diameter, Mach 1 would still be 21,506 rpm. I highly doubt any quadcopter is going to reach that with 6" blades. It's more when you get into [60" blades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Electric_GE90#Specifications) where you encounter supersonic tips.

Comment: @mins kv is not related to power, only related to the speed (1000RPM per volt, which at 8x4.2 is 33.6, so theoretical 33600 RPM) - if I wanted to include power, then the propeller pitch, air density, etc. would all come into play, whereas I wanted to keep it simple so I ignored that and focused only on the unloaded speed

Comment: @mins [Kv, not kV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor_constants) - confusing constant

Comment: @user2813274: Ah that's completely different. I didn't know of this Kv. I'm deleting my previous comments that are not relevant anymore. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for the link.

Comment: Nitpick, LHC accelerates protons (which are hadrons), not electrons (which are leptons).

Comment: I would add, that since the fans are shrouded, what is probably going on is that the prop is scraping against the shroud. Despite there being a gap between the prop and shroud, keep in mind that the shroud is shaped as an airfoil, producing "lift" towards the center of the prop, and is secured only on the bottom. The prop is some sort of molded plastic from what I can see, and it expands out from centrifugal forces. The result may be contact at high RPM, resulting in buzzing.

Answer (score 7):

It's possible, but I would say unlikely. Supersonic propeller tips really mess with efficiency.

The tip speed of many aircraft propellers is close to supersonic, and if not properly controlled can exceed the speed of sound, but most models don't get up that fast (and your blade tips don't have to be supersonic to be annoyingly loud).

There is a formula to figure out the speed of the blade tip. For your quadcopter multiply the blade RPM by the diameter (in inches), and multiply that by 0.00426

$ TipSpeed = RPM * Diameter * 0.00426 $

The result is in Feet per Second.
Anything over 1125 feet per second (343 meters per second) and your tips are supersonic.
Anything over about 650  feet per second (200 meters per second) and the propeller is probably *really loud and annoying*.

Comment: Can you provide this equation in meters too? Thanks!

Comment: How do I find blade rpm

Comment: @GabrielBrito As a Lazy American it would be easier for me to convert meters to inches (multiply by 39.36) and plug it into the formula I know

Comment: @Ethan ...the usual way is [with a tachometer](https://www.hobbyzone.com/hcap0401.html).

Comment: Its pretty loud so it must be over 650 feet per second. It also shoots up in the air at full thrust so it has to be over 650 feet per second.

Comment: @Ethan With a 0.5" blade length, that's *extremely* unlikely. See my answer. I've updated it to reflect the 0.5" blade length you mentioned recently in a comment.

Comment: @reirab I just measured the length of the blade. Did I measure the diameter correctly?

Comment: @Ethan The length of one blade should be the radius (assuming you measured blade length from the center of the prop to a blade tip.) The diameter is twice the radius, that is 1" in this case, the distance from one blade tip to the opposite blade tip.

Comment: @reirab So it is 1 then.

Comment: What is this magic number, `0.00426`?

Comment: @Brad: It's `pi` divided by `60` and `12`. Required to convert `rpm` to `rps`, then `in` to `ft`. In `meters`: `3.14 * d * rpm / 60`.

Comment: @mins Well, it's `3.14 * d * rpm / 60` regardless of whether you're using meters, feet, furlongs, or megaparsecs. :)

Comment: @reirab: Yes, if the diameter and the speed are using the same length unit. It was not the case in the answer (diameter in in, speed in ft/s -- so the additional division by 12).

Comment: Yeah this happens to be the "convenient" formula for the RC model propellers I used to use. There's a better formula (which also has altitude & temperature in it & has fewer "magic" unit conversions) but I was really lazy & just grabbed the easy formula from their website :-)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not. I fly a quad with similar-sized props (mine are 2.5 inches diameter), and there's NO WAY those break the sound barrier, even at full power, tens of thousands of RPM. It's actually very quiet. I think you might be hearing something loose rattling around on the quad- check that everything's tightened down, I took off with half the bottom plate hanging off my quad a few days ago, and I heard exactly the sound you're describing. I couldn't see that it was hanging off because I fly FPV, and I had the goggles on. Learn what your quad sounds like with everything secure so you can hear it when something's off- it saved me from busting the bottom plate off during an acro flight.